# Create array of classes in d

Tags: d

It's my class

```d
module figure;
import block; 
class Figure {
    Block[] body;
    this() {
        this.body ~= new Block();
    }
}
```

And I got "no identifier for declarator Block[]"

Block.d file

```d
module block;

import std.stdio;

class Block {
  this() {
    writeln("In block.d");
  }
}
```

Comment: what are the contents of the block.d file?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, the word `body` is a keyword in D and thus cannot be used as a variable name. Try just about any other name, maybe `body_` or just `blocks` or almost anything else and it will work.